# How to properly loop three dimensional array in twig?

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array, twig

I have an array setup like so; and I cant seem to loop through the values with twig:

```
array (size=1)
  'hash' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'key1' => "val"
          'key2' => "val"
          'key3' => "val"
          'key4' => "val"
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'key1' => "val"
          'key2' => "val"
          'key3' => "val"
          'key4' => "val"
      ...
```

The template code I'm using (in its nth iteration):

```
  {% for i in hash %}
    {% for j in i %}
      <td>{{ j.key1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ j.key2 }}</td>
      <td>{{ j.key3 }}</td>
      <td>{{ j.key4 }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

I keep getting `Array to string conversion` errors with the above twig template code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the help of vijay4vijju and his reference to `dump` I was able to loop over the array.

Only a single loop was needed:

```
{% for key,val in hash %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ val.key1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ val.key2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ val.key3 }}</td>
    <td>{{ val.key4 }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I would have selected his answer but it technically wasn't the answer, and dump was just a reference to the `dump` manual.

To enable debugging in twig I used:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'debug' => true,
));
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
```

To troubleshoot this issue I used:

```
{% for key,val in hash %}
  <pre>{{ dump(val) }}</pre>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ val.key1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ val.key2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ val.key3 }}</td>
    <td>{{ val.key4 }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I am not sure

```
  {% for key,value in hash %}
          {% for key1,value1 in value %}
               Value1 : {{ dump(value1) }}
                {% for key2,value2 in value1 %}
                     Value1 : {{ value2 }} 
                {% endfor %} 
         {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

dump will print the data from the array:

Refer [dump](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html)

Comment: Edited my answer  check once.  try dump  ?

Answer (score 0):

I used this for printing multi-dimensional array in twig, hopefully it will work.

```
{% for item in hash %}
    {% for firstLevelItem in item %}
        <ul>
            <li>{{ firstLevelItem.comments }}</li>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```